# Leaving a blank line for possible line break

Tags: css, html, line-breaks

Is there a way to leave a blank space incase a word is too long and breaks into 2 lines?

It's kinda hard to explain, please take a look at my screenshots

What it's like right now:
[image: before]

What I want it to look like:
[image: after]

You can see how the line break messes up the horizontal layout and I'm looking for a way to prevent that.

Comment: what about using a min-height to that div? p.s. Please upload your code so we can have a look of it and help you out

Comment: try to give min-height to the div that has the name of the product, see if that helps

Comment: Thanks guys! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a min-height to the product-title div worked out as suggested. Thanks!